# Extract information of a raster overlayed on another raster with a lower resolution directly in python

Tags: python, raster, python-2.7, overlay

I have two aligned rasters with the same extent, one has a resolution of 5 meters and the other of 125 meters. I would like to place the 5 meter one over the 125 meter one and assign to these smaller pixels the value of the large pixel on which they land on. How can I do this in pure python code? The raster I/O is not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way, using Numpy and GDAL.

Read your 125m resolution raster into an array that is 25x larger in each dimension. GDAL's I/O function decimates for you and this feature is available in Rasterio (https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/docs/windowed-rw.rst#decimation) and I assume also in osgeo.gdal. Ask the methods to write into an array that's bigger than the source image, and they upsample.

Using the gdalwarp utility with "nearest" interpolation would give you the same result.

GDAL: http://gdal.org

Rasterio: https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio